# PHP popen Application cannot open shared object

Tags: php, c++, linux, apache, apache2

I've created a simple C++ Application with the boost framework.
The Application is running correct from the command line.

After this I've created a PHP file with a `popen` to this binary.

```
<?php
  $handle = popen("./webParser", "r");
  //echo $handle . ":: " . gettype($handle);
  $read = fread($handle, 2096);
  echo $read;
  pclose($handle);
  //echo "done";
?>
```

After visiting the website I've got the following error message from `apache2/error_log`

```
./webParser: error while loading shared libraries: libboost_log.so.1.59.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

System is openSuse Linux.

**Steps done:**

- Insert lib path to /etc/ld.so.conf and running ldconfig

Comment: Is there a reason to not link the application statically?

Comment: i need to pass -DBOOST_LOG_DYN_LINK to get compiled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you have LD_LIBRARY_PATH set for user running your web server includes the location of the shared library you've built.